# Weakly $p$-summable sequences in $L_{r}$

Tags: banach-spaces

By Bessaga-Pelczynski Selection Principle, it is easy to check that both $l_{p}(1\leq p<2)$ and $l_{r}(1<r<p^{*})$ contains no normalized weakly $p$-summable sequences. I do not know if it is the case for $L_{r}[0,1]$. My question: Does
$L_{r}[0,1](1<r\leq 2)$ contain normalized weakly $p$-summable sequences$(1<p<2)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $L_r$ has cotype 2 for $r\le 2$.  In fact, every bounded linear operator from $\ell_q$ into $L_r$ is compact when $r \le 2 < q$.

Comment: Thanks,Bill. But I am not sure the proof of each operator from $l_{q}$ into $L_{r}$ is compact. It seems that your proof uses the cotype.

Comment: For a proof that does not mention  cotype see $$$$ Rosenthal, Haskell P. On quasi-complemented subspaces of Banach spaces, with an appendix on compactness of operators from Lp(μ) to Lr(ν). J. Functional Analysis 4 1969 176–214.